# ERROR ITMS-90205 The bundle contains disallowed nested bundles podfile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am getting the following error when deploying to AppStore

> ERROR ITMS-90205 The bundle contains disallowed nested bundles podfile

Both my App and Today Extension use Swift pods.

Here's my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'Eureka', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'NSString-HTML', '~> 0.0'
    pod 'TSMessages', :git => 'https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages.git'
    pod 'MCSMKeychainItem'
    pod 'HTProgressHUD', '~> 0.2.1'
    pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
    pod 'TOWebViewController', '~> 2.0.5'
    pod 'SimulatorStatusMagic', :configurations => ['Debug']
end

target 'MyAppTodayExtension' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'NSString-HTML', '~> 0.0'
    pod 'MCSMKeychainItem'
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** After installing a custom Run Script build phase for my Today Extension that removes the Frameworks directory, I am able to upload to App Store.

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then 
    rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```

But is there another way that is supported by CocoaPods?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading cocoapods to 0.38.2 version. I had that problem and I fixed by downgrading.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4203

Comment: 38.2 is just so old. I didn't want to downgrade that far back. I used a custom Run Script to remove the Frameworks directory inside the Today Extension. But I really want to find a solution supported by CocoaPods.